# Trying to use media queries to make header image responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, web-frontend

I am using Bootstrap 5 to make a website and I am trying to make the header image of the website responsive using media queries. I like the way it looks on desktop, laptop, and tablet viewports but on mobile, however, I am not able to get the text and button to fit well like it does in the other viewports.

### This is what it looks like on desktop [image]

### This is what it looks like on mobile

[image]

```css
:root {
    --desktop-min: 1200px;
    --laptop-min: 900px;
    --laptop-max: calc(var(--desktop-min) - 1px);
    --tablet-min: 720px;
    --tablet-max: calc(var(--laptop-min) - 1px);
    --mobile-min: 300px;
    --mobile-max: calc(var(--tablet-min) - 1px);
    }

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 500%;
    transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

.carousel-caption h4 {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    
}

/* .btn-primary {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
} */


#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#button:hover {
    background-color:hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
    border: 1px solid hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--laptop-min)) and (max-width: var(--laptop-max)) {
    
    
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 140%;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding-bottom: .2rem;
        
        
    }
    #button {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding: 8px 14px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: var(--tablet-min)) and (max-width: var(--tablet-max)) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 50%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 350%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        padding-bottom: .1rem;
        
        
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 95%;
        padding: 8px 14px;
        
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile-min)) and (max-width: var(--mobile-max)) {
    .carousel-caption {
        top: 40%;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 250%;
        padding-top: 10px;
        
        
        
    }
    
    .carousel-caption h4 {
        font-size: 110%;
        
        
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 90%;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        
    }

    .carousel-indicators {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test17.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    <!-- SHOWCASE START -->
    <section>
      <div id="herocarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
        
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/4900/3300" class="d-block w-100 c-img" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption ">
            
            <h1 class="display-1 fw-bolder text-capitalize">Project___ Name_____</h1>
            <h4 class=" text-uppercase" id="sub-header">Get your unique solution</h4>
            <a href="/Bootstrap-/ticket-form.html" >
              <button type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary px-4 py-2 fs-5 " 
              id="button"
            >
              Submit&nbsp;a&nbsp;Ticket
              

            </button>
            </a>
            
            </div>
          
        
        </div> 
      <!-- class="bg-dark text-white text-center text-sm-start p-5 p-lg-0" -->
      <!-- <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <div>
            <h1><span class="text-primary">Project___ Name_____</span></h1>
            <p class="lead py-4">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem. Quisquam
              voluptatum, voluptate, quibusdam, quia voluptas quod quos
              exercitationem quae voluptatibus doloribus quidem.
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Quote</button>
        </div>
        <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" alt="" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg block"/>
      </div> -->
    </section>
    <!-- SHOWCASE CLOSE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Snippets are very helpful if you (a) remove all code which is not necessary for reproducing the problem and (b) make sure all your image references refer to images which exist on the web. [Lorem Picsum](https://picsum.photos/) is a good source of images to use in snippets.

Comment: @BrettDonald ok thank you I fixed my question. Can you please help me with my question?

Answer (score 0):

Because `.carousel-caption` is `position: absolute`, it doesn't contribute to the size of its parents. You're then using `overflow: hidden` on `.carousel-inner`, which can hide content which isn't directly contributing towards the size of the container. You can use one of these, but both together is a problem.

For background image, it doesn't continue down because it's wide and is shrunk down by various `width: 100%` rules and so there's no more image left to display once its height runs out. For more options, perhaps it might be better to use CSS `background-image`. Or perhaps just set a background color and accept that not all of the bottom part of the page is covered by an image.

Comment: where am I using `overflow: hidden`. when i remove `position: absolute` nothing changes

Comment: When I look in the inspector there seems to be a source of `position: absolute` from both the CSS and JS (I assume that's Bootstrap). You may have to set `position: static` explicitly to get rid of the `position: absolute`.

Comment: well in my CSS I have `position absolute should I change that to static?

Comment: I think you should try it in order to see the difference and if that doesn't work try `position: static !important`. I'm not trying to "fix" the code, it's working as designed; I'm trying to help you understand the deficiencies so that you can fix it yourself. I don't know your page best, for example, I have no idea why you're using a carousel component when this page doesn't seem to need that type of interactivity, but perhaps there's a circumstance where it's required. Maybe getting rid of the carousel would help, but only you can judge that.

Comment: I tried changing it to static but it was not the solution to the problem. It just moved the entire caption outside of the image. The reason why I am using a carousel is because I am trying to create a carousel slider. The code I have in my question is just one slide from the original carousel. I am trying to make this one slide responsive so I can implement the code on all slides of the carousel. Also for some reason when I try to change certain properties of the font to make it smaller, it's not being applied.

Comment: I think I have got to the bottom of it.  
The JS is setting `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);` on `.carousel-caption`.
This is being interfered with by `bottom: 1.25rem` in the CSS. Get rid of `bottom` and if you want an equivalent then use `margin-top: -1.25rem`, although you might need to tweak the amount.

Comment: do you mean the `padding-bottom` properties because there is no `bottom: 1.25rem` in the CSS. And none of the `padding-bottom` properties are set to 1.25rem. I commented out all the `padding-bottom` properties and added margin-top: -1.25rem;` and nothing happened. I am really sorry about all this trouble and I really and I wanted to let you know I appreciated all your help with this problem.

Comment: I don't know why this problem is occurring it should be as simple as changing the `font-size` of everything but I  noticed that when I try to change the size of something in the tablet, laptop, and mobile viewports nothing changes. Changes only occur when I apply them to the desktop viewport

Comment: The `bottom` is coming from the bootstrap.min.css that's included in the page. See https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css for a non-minified version. You could override it by setting `bottom: auto`.

Comment: I haven't looked into the `font-size` issue, but the bootstrap CSS does include some media queries and so it's possible that they're more specific than the CSS you're using. Try adding [!important](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) and see if it helps. Look in the browser inspector to see what's taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Im a newbie, but to address the issue with the mobile viewport, here are a few suggestions:

1. **Adjust Top Position of Caption:** You've already adjusted the `top` position of the `.carousel-caption` element in your media query for mobile devices. You could try further adjusting this value to find the optimal position for the caption text and button on mobile screens. Keep testing different values until you achieve the desired look.
2. **Font Sizes and Padding:** In your media query for mobile, you've adjusted the font sizes and padding of the caption elements and button. You can continue tweaking these values to make the text and button look good on mobile devices. Keep in mind that font sizes that are too small might make the text difficult to read, so find a balance.
3. **Button Styling:** You're adjusting the font size and padding of the button, which is great. However, you might also want to adjust the width of the button so that it doesn't span the entire width of the viewport on mobile devices. This can make it look more visually appealing.
4. **Carousel Indicators:** You've hidden the carousel indicators in your mobile media query. If these indicators are not necessary on smaller screens, this is a good approach. However, make sure you test the carousel navigation thoroughly after making this change.
5. **Testing on Actual Devices:** Sometimes, testing on an actual mobile device can provide a clearer picture of how your website looks on different screen sizes. Mobile emulators and developer tools can sometimes have limitations.

Remember that responsiveness can be a bit tricky to fine-tune, and it often requires a bit of trial and error to get everything looking just right. Keep iterating and testing to achieve the desired results on all screen sizes.

*`*Hopes this helps you a little, buddy. Best code & wish3s.*`*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Start with something very simple. Set height 100% and add a background image sized to cover the document.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1500);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Then build from there

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/1500);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font: bold 50px sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
Hello
```

Comment: I have to start over?